# Do something after a music ends with SoundPlayer

Tags: c#, audio, soundplayer

I need to do something after my Async Loaded music file finishes. Let's say I want the program to exit or something. Now how do I make it do is after the music finishes?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.SoundLocation = @"Music\" + FileList[0];
        player.LoadAsync();
    }

    private void Player_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (player.IsLoadCompleted)
        {
            player.PlaySync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type is the variable `player`? SoundPlayer, MediaPlayer, .. what?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for that.. in the title I meant SoundPlayer not PlaySound...

Comment: @TomLenc I wrote something in another answer that may help you, it has an event you can subscribe to when the sound is finished: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905192/soundplayer-stop-does-not-stop-sound-playback/29906524#29906524

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392396/how-to-know-when-soundplayer-has-finished-playing-a-sound

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I was looking at that page before but did not understand the rihgt answer at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `PlaySync` method is synchronous then it will not return until the file has been played to the end. So, you can simply do it like this:

```
if (player.IsLoadCompleted)
{
    player.PlaySync();
    DoSomethingAfterMusicIsDone();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

`LoadAsync` seems to run synchronously if the `SoundLocation` points to a file on the file system. This means that you should invoke `LoadAsync` on another thread if you don't want to freeze the UI thread. Here is an example:

```
Task.Run(() => player.LoadAsync());
```

Comment: If I understood it right... async load makes it run on a different thread so it wont freeze the window... that means... that it's like thread.sleep, which stays there for the specified ammount of time.. is it something like this?

Comment: @TomLenc, I am not sure I understand your question. async means you don't keep waiting for the thing to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use MediaPlayer instead:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Media Ended"); };
mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(@"C:\myfile.mp3"));
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Sounds good in theory.  However, in truth, I couldn't get the MediaEnded Event to fire.  Thus, I had to poll for the end of MediaEvent as follows:

```
while(true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    string pos = "unknown";
    string dur = "unknown";

    try 
    {
        pos = mediaplayer1.Position.Ticks.ToString();
        dur = mediaplayer1.NaturalDurataion.TimeSpan.Ticks.ToString()
        if (pos == dur)
        {
            // MediaEnded!!!!!
            pos = "0";
            dur = "0";
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
```

On the positive side, you can update your Audio player Slider by polling...
On the downside, it makes the pause button a little bit unresponsive if you notice 1000 milliseconds lag...

If you use this workaround, I would recommend placing the Mediaplayer in a background thread so that the polling loop doesn't lock up the UI thread.