# Playing sound after sound in c#

Tags: c#, audio

i have another dummy question for which i can't found good answer.

I have this program where i would like to play first sound, after which i would like to play second sound.

Basicly those sounds are supose to be different phrases like "this is sound number" "one" and son on and on.

I don't know why, but simple using various SoundPlayers results only with playing last sound- "one".

```
        SoundPlayer dzwiek = new SoundPlayer(@"E:\sokol\mp3\zdjecie_nr.wav");
        SoundPlayer dzwiek2 = new SoundPlayer(@"E:\sokol\mp3\1.wav");

        dzwiek.Play();
        dzwiek2.Play();
```

Would you kindly explain me why this is happening, and what should I do to prevent this issue problem in future?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer here..

[How to know when SoundPlayer has finished playing a sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392396/how-to-know-when-soundplayer-has-finished-playing-a-sound)

Basically, use PlaySync. You'll most likely want to do this on a different thread.

If you want some ordering, it might be a good idea to just queue your sound events (to some limitation) and PlaySync on a background worker. Will have to consider you can run into some issues if a sound plays for a very long time and things get delayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `SoundPlayer` class, which I've never used.  The documentation makes clear that the `Play` method is asynchronous, but I couldn't find any indication that you could get a notification when it's done playing.  This means that if you want to play two sounds synchronously, you'll have to use the `PlaySync` method, which has the unfortunate side-effect of freezing your GUI or requiring you to do the threading yourself.